# How do I apply css using jquery only when the element has a certain attribute?

Tags: jquery, css, this, attr

I'm trying to use jQuery to add some css to elements, but only if they have a certain attribute.

The reason why I'm not using just css is because the content for the site is too vast to go through and add classes to all the elements I want to style.

The jQuery code I'm using is this:

```
if ($('.body_text a').attr('name')) {
    $(this).css({
        'display': 'inline-block',
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '-200px',
        'visibility': 'hidden'
    })
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. If I put an alert inside the if statement the alert works. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `$('.body_text a[name]')`

Comment: Per W3: The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the jQuery selector you're looking for:**

```
//de or: $('.body_text a[name="value"]').css({
$('.body_text a[name]').css({
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'position': 'relative',
    'top': '-200px',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

**You can do this with CSS too:**

```
.body_text a[name] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$(this)` doesn't actually refer to anything — It needs to be placed in a function to refer to something.

However, the following code goes through all `a`s with a `name` attribute, and applies the styles to each one.

```
$('.body_text a[name]').css({
     'display': 'inline-block',
     'position': 'relative',
     'top': '-200px',
     'visibility': 'hidden'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should do the trick:

```
if( $('.body_text a').attr('name') == "TEXT HERE" ){
     // Do something
} else {
     // Do Something else
}
```

Make sure to loop through using the .each on the element you are looking for.

```
$('.body_text a').each(function(){
```

Comment: You can do this plainly with css though. .body_text a[name="Text Here] { followed by your css }

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the documentation:

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

I guess this is your problem?

Comment: Is this an answer? This seems like a comment.